# Application context is lost when using Callable method in a WorkManager

Tags: java, autowired, applicationcontext, workmanagers

I have implemented a WorkManager in WLS and I call an asynchronous task using schedule. 
When I received the request in the asynchronous task I have lost all @Autowired references of my application context.

Is there any way to use the variables of my application context inside the method "startTask" of the asynchronous task (class ExecuteProcessServiceImpl) ?

**Class that calls the async task**

```
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        String wmName = "java:comp/env/wm/wm0";
        WorkManager workManager = (WorkManager) ctx.lookup(wmName);
        Work work = new WorkInstance();
        workManager.schedule(work, new MyWorkListener());
```

**Class that receives the request and start the task**

```
public class WorkInstance implements Work {

private ExecuteProcessServiceImpl task = new ExecuteProcessServiceImpl();

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        new Callable<ExecuteProcessServiceImpl>() {
            @Override
            public ExecuteProcessServiceImpl call() {
                task.startTask();
                return task;
            }
        }.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Asynchronous Task**

```
public class ExecuteProcessServiceImpl implements ExecuteProcessService {

@Autowired
private MyAutowiredObj obj;

public void startTask() {
    // The application context is lost here 
    // The value of "obj" is null
}
```

Comment: You are directly creating `ExecuteProcessServiceImpl` instead of having Spring to create and populate it with all `@Autowired` beans. You need to lookup `ExecuteProcessServiceImpl` just like you do with `WorkManager` and pass it to `WorkInstance`.

Comment: @tsolakp  could you please give me an example?